# Excel to Powerpoint (But with tables not pictures)

Tags: excel, automation, powerpoint, vba

I am attempting to automate powerpoint creation with table created in Excel. My issue is after the table pastes into powerpoint, it is not considered 'selected' right away. I get an error that generally that says something like 'no object selected' or "Method 'ShareRange' of object 'Selection' failed". If I slowly go through the code with F8 it works, for the most part, it's when it runs it doesn't work.

In any case I've tried using the table's name (which when copies in the table gets the name 'table 1' imagine that), I've tried having it wait a few seconds and a few other things. I've tried different types of pasting into the file, however I need to keep it a table, not a picture (I have my code working if I only needed a picture). **My issue (I think) is that it pastes and is not selected immediately.**

I have modified it a bit and just am showing where the errors are, I also do this same paste, move, size, over and over. I really hope it's a 1 line - smack my face because it's obvious fix...

```
    Dim pp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim Slide1Title As Excel.Range
    'Opening a blank, normally I have it open a template
    Set pp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, 12)
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(2, 12)
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(3, 12)
    pp.Visible = True


   'Paste as text/table
   'Title 1
    PPPres.Slides(2).Select
    Set Slide1Title = Sheets("presentation").Range("B2:G3")
    Slide1Title.Copy
    PPPres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    'Here-ish is the error, after pasting in I can't seem to select it
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 10
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common problem.  The most recently pasted shape will always be "on top" so you can use something like this to get at it:

```
PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes(PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes.Count)
```

Note that by selecting shapes and slides, you open yourself up to weird errors and slow down your code by an order of magnitude.

```
Dim oSh as Shape
With PPPres.Slides(2)
  ' Do the paste, then get a reference to the pasted shape:
  Set oSh = PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes(PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes.Count)
  With oSh
     ' set .Top, .Left etc
  End With   ' the shape
End With  ' the slide
```

Comment: When I run the code it has the same old error but item instead of shape... and then when I F8 through the code, I get Shapes(Unknown member): Integer  out of range. 0 is not in the valid range of 1 to 0.

Comment: GOT IT (I orignally deleted the select slide item... i thought the with PPPres.Slides(2) was going to select the slide as well... or paste it in the right spot... wrong... it pastes on whichever is selected... even if it says 'with slide 2 paste' but thanks so much! some small nuances I was missing, I've seen this code before but i kept putting it in incorrectly. Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad it worked ... suggestion:  pay it back by posting an answer with the final code, or editing what you have already and noting that it now works.  Then others will be able to benefit from what you've learned.

Comment: Hmm when I said Got it.... guess I spoke too soon... it was only for when I walked through the code 'F8'... So it works... but only when manually going through... I've tried wait and sleep functions... doesnt seep to be doing it... I had the code up for a minute then took it down :(

Comment: So I can run it with a MsgBox("<something>") which basically helps stop the code... but I'd prefer something... less... click intensive...

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution, when not using F8

```
Set Slide1Title = Sheets("presentation").Range("B2:G3")
Slide1Title.Copy
PPPres.Slides(2).Select
With PPPres.Slides(2)
PPPres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
MsgBox ("1")
Set oSh = PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes(PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes.Count)

    With oSh
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 10
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 75
    End With   ' the shape
End With  ' the slide
```